# Disabling Bouncy Castle

Tags: ssl, certificate, tls1.2, bouncycastle, tls1.3

The application is currently running in java version build 1.7.0_79-b15 and the third party application upgraded its TLS to 1.3 version.  We can't easily upgrade java version that will support TLS 1.3 and so we decided to use Bouncy Castle in order for us comply with the third party.  We were able to connect to the third party system after using Bouncy Castle but, the existing mail service that is working on previous default java security is no longer working due to the error below.

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: certificate_unknown(46)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:625)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: certificate_unknown(46)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient$1.notifyServerCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.processServerCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleServerCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at javax.activation.URLDataSource.getInputStream(URLDataSource.java:107)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:304)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:845)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:361)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:85)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:883)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:845)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:361)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:85)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:883)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1683)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:585)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to find certificate chain.
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.validateChain(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
```

Are there any way to disable Bouncy Castle or processing certificate when sending message through SMTP? Or any way to fix it?
Any suggestions or help are highly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: You are running an insecure version of Java and should upgrade. For this question you could try setting property `mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory.class`: "If set, specifies the name of a class that extends the javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory class. This class will be used to create SMTP SSL sockets." to the Sun provided one instead of the Bouncy Castle SocketFactory. Information taken from [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html). You can also do this programmatically of course, but I don't know if you have that kind of control.

Comment: I would suggest checking what trust store (e.g. cacerts, jssecacerts or other specified using javax.net.ssl.trustStore system property) is being used. Possibly the configuration using BC is on a different JDK installation or in some other way is different such that it is not loading the same trust store.

Comment: i've tried overriding the socketFactory class but it leads me into another error



Caused by: org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: unexpected_message(10); Unsupported UNKNOWN(50)
 at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.checkRecordType(Unknown Source)

Comment: Before applying Bouncy Castle, we are not using any certificate for mail server.

Comment: I was able to find a solution for this issue.  The application is currently using Apache Email, when I used Java Mail, it works perfectly fine with Bouncy Castle.